# Mapping a command in Visual Mode results in error E481: No range alllowed

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode, neovim

I'm trying to make a keyboard binding in Neovim that would send a selected block to the opened Neovim terminal. I've used these answers as guidelines https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3390/3405 https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271254/859391

Though when i'm trying to call the  command with a Visual Line selected I keep getting the No Range Allowed error. Am I missing something obvious?

```
function! s:get_visual_selection()
  " Why is this not a built-in Vim script function?!
  let [lnum1, col1] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
  let [lnum2, col2] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
  let lines = getline(lnum1, lnum2)
  let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: col2 - (&selection == 'inclusive' ? 1 : 2)]
  let lines[0] = lines[0][col1 - 1:]
  return join(lines, "\n")
endfunction

augroup Terminal
  au!
  au TermOpen * let g:last_terminal_job_id = b:terminal_job_id
augroup END

function! REPLSend(lines)
  call jobsend(g:last_terminal_job_id, lines[0])
  call jobsend(g:last_terminal_job_id, "\r") " needed for the way REPL handles the input
endfunction

command! REPLSendLine call REPLSend([s:get_visual_selection()])
vnoremap <silent> <leader>l :REPLSendLine<cr>
" leader is <Space>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think that when you hit `<leader>l` to call `:REPLSendLine`, Vim automatically inserts the visual range `'<,'>`, and since your command is not defined with the attribute `-range`, it raises an error.

In your visual mapping, you should probably add the keycode `<C-U>` to remove the visual range (it won't affect the marks `'<` and `'>`, they will still be valid inside `s:get_visual_selection()`):

```
vnoremap <silent> <leader>l :<C-U>REPLSendLine<cr>
```

Also, maybe you could try removing the inline comment `" needed for the way REPL handles the input` and put it on a separate and dedicated line.

Comment: Thank you. ":<C-U>" did the trick. Also, the comment I've added it only for this question, to make it more clear what I was going for.